# Laravel 5 two-way table login

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I am trying to configure a laravel 5 app that will login users based on their username with password, if the username and password method fails the app will try to check the other table if the data in the username variable is available in my case their employee_id. So here is my code for logging users in with the conventional laravel method:

```
 $authdetails = array(
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password')
         );
         if (Auth::attempt($authdetails)) {
             // Authentication passed...
             return redirect()->to('/home');
         }
        else {
              return back()->with('error', 'Invalid username or password')->withInput();
          }
     }
```

I have two tables inside the database. (1)users, (2)userdetails, the user table contains your standard laravel users default migration table, the userdetails table contains the details for the user. The first method of the login authentication uses the users table, the second method of login I want to implement if the first fails uses the userdetails table.

What I'm trying to do is if the first method of the login fails, it will search the other table for a value of the variable passed if there is then it will authenticate it.

Comment: What does your schema look like? Is `employee_id` a column in the user table? How are Users and Employees related?

Comment: Edited question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `employee_id` column in your users table, then it's really easy. You just try to authenticate with both sets of credentials.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'usernameOrEmployeeId' => 'required',
        'password'             => 'required',
    ]);

    // Attempt login via username
    $credentials = [
        'username' => $request->input('usernameOrEmployeeId'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
    ];
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    // Swap username and employee_id
    $credentials['employee_id'] = $request->input('usernameOrEmployeeId');
    unset($credentials['username']);

    // Attempt login via employee_id
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    // Login attempts failed
    return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput($request->only('usernameOrEmployeeId', 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            'usernameOrEmployeeId' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}
```

If you don't have an `employee_id` column in your users table, then it's a bit more difficult. You would use the same code as above, except you would replace this part:

```
// Swap username and employee_id
$credentials['employee_id'] = $credentials['username'];
unset($credentials['username']);
```

with something like this:

```
// Find user_id by looking up the employee relationship
$employee = App\Employee::findOrFail($request->input('usernameOrEmployeeId'));
$credentials['id'] = $employee->user->id;
unset($credentials['username']);
```

Don't forget the `unset()`. It is important because if you leave username in the array, Laravel will try to authenticate with all 3 pieces of info and will always fail because we already know the username/password don't match.

Also, you don't have to use any third party libraries. This is a simple problem with a relatively simple solution.

Comment: Tested and works. Although it's alot of hard coding to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login with two different table when first one is failed to authenticate.You have to use multiauth library [Here](https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth) and [Here](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/sboo/multiauth).

and then use like this.

```
$authdetails = array(
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password')
     );
     if (Auth::user1()->attempt($authdetails)) {
         // Authentication passed...
         return redirect()->to('/home1');
     }
     if (Auth::user2()->attempt($authdetails)) {
         // Authentication passed...
         return redirect()->to('/home2');
     }
    else {
          return back()->with('error', 'Invalid username or password')->withInput();
      }
 }
```